# Trying to make a responsive menu but having problems with ::before and ::after

Tags: css

I have this pen: https://codepen.io/cesarnascimento/pen/qvLmPG

And he has a red box that when you click, it was supposed to show the menu. It works just fine, and I tried to make a line for the menu, using the `::before` and `::after` but it wont work.

This is my code:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
header .logo {
  margin: 0;
}
header .nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
header .nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
  display: block;
}
header nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
header nav ul li a {
  color: cyan;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
header .nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header .nav-toggle-label span {
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
header .nav-toggle-label span::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
header .nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="logo">Logoe</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Monitoria</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Fale comigo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</header>
```

[image]

[image]

Using Chrome Developer and I can see the line but it wont appear in my front. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are expecting the result of the line(s) to be? They are there, but not visible because they have no background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `background-color` to the `::before` and `::after` elements. In case you don't add a `background-color` the background is transparent and the elements are not visible:

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
header .logo {
  margin: 0;
}
header .nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
header .nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
  display: block;
}
header nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
header nav ul li a {
  color: cyan;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
header .nav-toggle-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header .nav-toggle-label span {
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
  background:#000;
}
header .nav-toggle-label span::before {
  content: "";
  background:#000;
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top:-6px;
}
header .nav-toggle-label span::after {
  content: "";
  background:#000;
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top:6px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="logo">Logoe</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Monitoria</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Fale comigo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</header>
```